# How to get the Query executed using ResultSet?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I have a `preparedStatement` called `PrepStatement`
which contains a Select Query like

`Select a, b from abc where ab="cd".`

executed below

```
ResultSet selectParams = PrepStatement.executeQuery();
```

Is there anyway i can get the executed Query with parameters passed from `ResultSet` object?

I can get it from `PrepStatement` object, But i want to get it from `ResultSet` or `ResultSetMetadata`.

Comment: Can't you just log the parameter values and the SQL itself before executing it? I can't think of a way to get it from the ResultSet Object.

Comment: I can do that, But just searching.. If anyone has any idea or technique to get that after executing from ResultSet

Comment: There are circumstances where the original statement isn't available, such as when a ResultSet object is passed to (or returned by) a method, and where neither the statement instance nor the SQL query is available. I'll continue to investigate, but my initial take is we're SOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get it from any of those actually.

Hard to see why you're even asking, when you already have a solution: getting it from the `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

resultSet.getStatement() should give u the query and some extra information